# Timestamp & Watermark assigning for two input streams, later connected for dynamic alerting using 'EventTime'

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I have a Flink program which takes in two streams i.e. Data/sensor readings stream and alert rules stream. I am broadcasting rules stream and connecting it to a data stream for generating dynamic alerts. Everything is working fine with ProcessingTime but nothing is working with EventTime.
I have assigned timestamp & watermark to my data stream and passing rules stream as it is (as rules stream will have records only when a new additional rule/update is seen). But no alerts are generated.

1. How can one use 'EventTime' to generate alerts when two streams i.e. one with timestamp & watermarks and one stream with just rules (broadcasted) are connected and processed dynamically according to rule.
2. Do I necessarily need to assign timestamp and watermark to my rules stream as well?
3. Since my rules stream will have records only when there is any addition/modification. Is there any workaround or a hack to avoid/overcome this situation?

Any help/suggestion would be grateful.

-- What I tried !
I tried with just one stream i.e. Data stream, by generating alerts with hardcoded window rules. And it is working fine. But when I connect it with rules stream, it fails to generate any alerts/output.

Everything is working fine with 'ProcessingTime' but not with 'EventTime'.

--What I expect!
I expect my program to work, when I connect a continuous data stream with a non-continous rules stream, to generate dynamic alerts using 'EventTime'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exercise in the Flink training covers exactly this case: https://training.ververica.com/exercises/taxiQuery.html. See the hints and the solution for details, but the approach taken there is to use this timestamp extractor / watermark generator on the stream with the rules:

```
// Once the two streams are connected, the Watermark of the KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction operator
// will be the minimum of the Watermarks of the two connected streams. Our query stream has a default
// Watermark at Long.MIN_VALUE, and this will hold back the event time clock of the
// KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction, unless we do something about it.
public static class QueryStreamAssigner implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<String> {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        return Watermark.MAX_WATERMARK;
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(String element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This has the effect of leaving the other stream completely in charge of the watermarks, which is what is wanted in this case.

Comment: Hi @David, Thank you.
Yes, I did use the same trick and it worked. But, I am testing whether it has any other side effects or not.
Would be grateful, if you can advise on this.

Comment: The only potential issue I can think of is a rather obvious one: without timestamps on the rules stream, if that stream can be processed out-of-order, you have no way to detect this is happening and correct for it.

Comment: Our Rules stream will have records only for addition/modification and will be unique. Also, rules are copied to broadcast state based on the rule_id.
So, as per my understanding, there are very rare chances for chaos. (Please correct me if not so!)

Comment: I suggest you use a single, non-parallel source for the rules. This will avoid any chance of permutting the order.